# How to check radio button automatically with third-party program

Tags: winforms, testing, radio-button

I'm making a web that provides multiple choice tests, but I'm too lazy to test it the human way. I want to write a simple C# .Net winform program that help me to check every A (or B, C, D) radio button of the question in the web browser. I wonder if a winform application could do that.

Thank for reading :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, your main goal isn't to write a C# winforms application, but simply to test your web form. Therefore, instead of spending time to create a dedicated C# application to test your website, I'd suggest you look into dedicated web testing solutions.
There is a very similiar question here already:
[How apply Unit tests in ASP.NET webforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554756/how-apply-unit-tests-in-asp-net-webforms)

If you don't like that, then another option would be to generate test scripts for the [FireFox iMacros extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/pl/firefox/addon/imacros-for-firefox/). The syntax is fairly simple.

Generally speaking, you should look into the topic of existing solutions for testing web forms. It is not advisable to create a dedicated solution simply for that purpose.

---

**EDIT:**

Ok, from your comment I see that it's important for you to have this solution in WinForms, therefore I'll rectify my answer.
To do this in WinForms, perform the following steps:

1. Use the [WebBrowser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class - add the relevant WebBrowser control to your winform.
2. Add a button, you can call it "btnTest".
3. Double-click this button in the editor, so a btnTest_Click(...) method stub is created.
4. In code, set the desired browser address string like so: `string address = @"D:\path\to\my\file.html"` or use a http:// address instead if you want that.
5. Navigate to this address using the [WebBrowser.Navigate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161352%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, like so: `webBrowser.Navigate(new Uri(address));`

This can all run in Form1's constructor after `InitializeComponent();` or wherever else you want (on another button combined with an address textbox perhaps?).
Now for your test button code. To perform tests you can use [WebBrowser.Document's methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get [HtmlElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)s and perform actions on them. See the provided documentation links for details.

Some examples:

```cs
HtmlElement checkboxGenderFemale = webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("female");
checkboxGenderFemale.InvokeMember("CLICK");
```

This will simulate a click and check the given checkbox. Remember to assign IDs to all your elements. To fill out a text input, you can use this code snippet:

```
HtmlElement nameInput = webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("firstname");
nameInput.SetAttribute("value", "NewName");
```

As you can see, you can simulate clicks and modify attributes of elements with ease. You can put those code examples in your `btnTest_Click(...)` method and see how it works. If you've done the navigation in Form1's constructor, the form should open with the page already loaded. After btnTest is clicked, the relevant test will be performed.

Comment: Actually, I am really interested in write this c# winform, I just like to write it to learn more, I don't want to download because write and use my own software is one of my hobbies :) help me plz

Comment: I see. Didn't think WinForms was the main focus of this question to be honest, thought it was web testing. Updated my post with relevant information. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank for your help, but I got problem that webBrowser.Document is null even after I use webBrowser.Navigate(new Uri(address)); , but what I want is to click that on my current Firefox browser's tab, so I can see it's clearly on the browser.

Comment: Did you navigate to a proper, working URI? You should see the webpage loaded in your Form. Null is only returned if the webpage hasn't loaded properly.

Comment: Ah, I got it, because the page require to login. but anyway, if it's load on my form, I can't test it on firefox.

Comment: As I stated - Firefox extensions such as iMacros are for testing on Firefox. If you want to test using C# and WinForms - the WebBrowser class is for that. Those are two separate applications - Firefox and your WinForms app. In a way, separate worlds. You can't interface with Firefox from a C# application level. That is why I gave you a solution how to test in Firefox (suggested iMacros as it's seemingly the best option here) and a C# solution for WinForms, since you needed that.

Comment: Awesome, thank for your kindly help, so I guess the answer is I need to make a Firefox Add-on, I happen to see someone did make a add-on which can auto check radio button, but what a shame that it's is randomly check :( thank again man ;) I'll mark your answer as accept answer.
But I'm also thinking about hack Firefox, like Trainer and see Firefox as a game.